# $\sin(x)$ is asymptotically equal to $x+5x^3$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, asymptotics, equivalence-relations

Here is my question: I've never seen before this kind of fact underlined about asymptotic equalities (and why we keep only one term in these equalities) and I'm looking for reference. Here is an example: we know that 
$$\sin(x) \underset{x\to 0}{\sim} x,$$
and also (the $5x^3$ is in fact arbitrary)
$$ x+5x^3 \underset{x\to 0}{\sim} x,$$
so, since $\underset{x\to 0}{\sim}$ is an equivalence relation,
$$\sin(x) \underset{x\to 0}{\sim} x+5x^3.$$
I've never seen this in a book or a course, do you have any reference for this amusing fact? Or others exercises on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

We can reformulate the question like this.

$\sin(x) \underset{x\to 0}{\sim} x,$ means that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $.

$ x+5x^3 \underset{x\to 0}{\sim} x,$ means that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+5x^3}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1+5x^2 \right)=1$.

So since $=$ is also an equivalence relation, we can say that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+5x^3}{x} = 1. $$

Of course the [*rate of convergence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) could be different. To describe the behavior of the limits we can use [*asymptotic analysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).

Comment: It's a good comment, I was asking for references.